# pool of free page frames OS

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, virtual-memory, paging

I read that in a paging scheme memory management, some os's have a paging daemon that wakes up periodically to inspect the memory of the RAM. This is to ensure that modified pages can be scheduled to write back to disk before page fault happens and it also makes it more efficient to have a pool of free frames rather than having all frames used when a page fault occurs. OS periodically moves pages from RAM to a "pool of free page frames".

1) My question is since the pages are moved to this pool of free page frames, then it must be stored somewhere into RAM ? because the OS can easily retrieve the pages should if the frame it was evicted from has not have pages put inside. So is there memory reserved to store this "pool of page frames" in OS reserved memory ?